# Why am I getting none? I am trying to have one list of standard deviations

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop

My goal is to have one list of standard deviations from the data. I have 13 columns (features) in trainx and three labels(1,2,3) in trainy array corresponding to each row of trainx. My purpose is to find a feature which has minimum standard deviation.

I thought that first I'll calculate standard deviation for each feature for label 1, append it in a list and then will find the minimum std deviation. I tried to write below code blocks but have been unsuccessful so far:

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,13):
    b=[np.std(trainx[trainy==1,i])]
    print(a.append(b))
```

It is returning this output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

If I try below code:

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,13):
    b=[np.std(trainx[trainy==1,i])]
    a=a.append(b)
print(a)
```

it returns:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-6b02e93115a0> in <module>
      3 for i in range(0,13):
      4     b=[np.std(trainx[trainy==1,i])]
----> 5     a=a.append(b)
      6 print(a)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Please help me. Other ways are welcome too.

Comment: The `append()` method always returns `None`. You need `a.append(b)` inside the loop and `print(a)` outside.

Comment: Appending to a list doesn't return the list, or anything: it returns `None`. The list *itself*, however, is altered. Print the list outside your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) doesn't return the `list`. It only appends the object to the `list`. To get the list after you append, just access the list.

```py
a=[]
for i in range(0,13):
    b=[np.std(trainx[trainy==1,i])]
    a.append(b)
    print(a)
```